# In UnityScripting C#, What's the distinction between global coordinates and world space?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation, gameobject

In Unity game engine and C# scripting;
Is there any distinction between global space and world space? 
Are this two the same thing and identical or there is a distinction?
I'm not confusing between local and global. 
The relation between local-global is the same to local-world?
Can I exchange this two words (global and world) without creating confusion?

for example in the Unity manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Transforms.html

Make a distinction adding "or":

> world space or global coordinates.

Comment: Global/world space are the same thing. The other space is local/mode-view

Comment: Shoot meant to say model-view not mode... And yes by extension local has the same relation to world as it does to global as they are interchangeable

Comment: In Unity making courses I here this distinction for this particular game engine. Here is the source video at 04:02 link: http://3dmotive.com/series/advanced-c-in-unity-5/291/2635.

Comment: Where is your source n_palum?

Comment: You'll have to state the exact words they use, because we won't pay to buy the course just to answer the question.

Comment: Because it's really a generic question, not specific to Unity.

Comment: ^ I don't think I need a source but I can pull up the explanations for them if you really want.. As @AlexandreVaillancourt stated, it's a general thing not engine specific

Comment: I can not make a question about a specific game engine? and a separate question in general? In stackoverflow.com I can do that. Can I change the question to UnityScript and UnityC#? .Please look this question history.

Comment: @Soaring this is not SO, it just seems like rep hunting.

Comment: There's nothing here that is Unity specific. The terms are generic 3D terms. I think this question is _better_ as one that doesn't bother with "Unity" in the text or title, but I'm not going to get into a rollbar war with you over it. If you want to leave it this way, that's fine. There's no reason to make two questions though.

Comment: This is about scripting quaternion in C# the other is in general terminology

Comment: This is a very generic question. The fact you are using Unity has no real bearing on the answer, as it is a very basic core concept in 3D. For this reason, anything you learn here can be used *outside* of Unity. Great, if you move to other software that works in global/world and local space.

Comment: Put in duplicated this one and answer the more general one. Here is the link http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139081/in-general-whats-the-distinction-between-global-space-and-world-space

Comment: Instead of having us swap around two questions that basically ask the same thing, why don't you just revert the original edit to make *this* question the more generic one?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is basically the difference between relative and absolute positions.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html

So that a child gameObject's position/rotation/scale can be relative to it's parent (0, 0 is bottom left of window not screen) instead of

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Which is absolute. (0, 0 is middle or bottom left of screen depending on anchors)

there is a toggle for this Local/Global setting in the toolbar too

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

[image]

Click the Local/Global button on the right to toggle between Local and Global.

- Local keeps the Gizmo’s rotation relative to the GameObject’s.
- Global clamps the Gizmo to world space orientation.

Comment: So the gismo unity Vector3 "rotation" that is in the inspector not accessible via coding are relative global values activated via this button and the C# functions as for example InverseTransformPoint are world absolute value.

Comment: ya the button is only for editing in editor with mouse or inspector... from source code use transform.localPosition for local (usually always) and transform.position for global